# Join statement with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, database

Ok I have two mysql table one called books and the other reading_tracking.
I have written the join query below:
`$query = "SELECT * FROM books inner join reading_tracking on book_num = book_id;`
My dilemma is that i don't want all the from books i want a query which in theory would look something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM books 
where reading_status = 1 inner 
join SELECT * FROM reading_tracking 
on book_num = book_id";
```

If i try this as suggested:

```
SELECT * FROM books b 
INNER JOIN reading_tracking rt 
ON b.book_id = rt.book_num 
WHERE rt.reading_status = 1;
```

The thing is in my program not all books in books table are in reading_tracking,  user have to make an additional step, so i don't want books that are similar in both tables i want all the books from books where reading_status = 1; but want all the books from reading_tracking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume column `book_num` is from `books` table, column `book_id` is from `reading_tracking` table. First join the 2 tables then use `WHERE` to filter the condition:

```
SELECT * FROM books b
INNER JOIN reading_tracking r
    ON b.book_num = r.book_id
WHERE b.reading_status = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax should have the `SELECT [x] FROM` followed by the `INNER JOIN`, and then you need an `ON` to denote which field is synonymous between the two tables. In your example, I'm assuming you have a column `book_id` in `books`, and a column `book_num` in `reading_tracking`.

The **[`WHERE` clause](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm)** should come **after** the `ON`, and additionally should specify which of the two tables you want to look for the column in.

This can be seen in the following:

```
SELECT * FROM books b
INNER JOIN reading_tracking rt
ON b.book_id = rt.book_num 
WHERE rt.reading_status = 1;
```

This will search `books` for any row that has a `reading_status` of `1` in the `reading_tracking` table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery before doing the [JOIN](http://mysqltutorial.org/basic-mysql-tutorial-aspx/mysql-join/) as shown below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM books WHERE reading_status=1) A 
INNER JOIN reading_tracking B on B.book_num=A.book_id;
```

See [Using MySQL Alias To Make The Queries More Readable](http://mysqltutorial.org/basic-mysql-tutorial-aspx/mysql-alias/)